# libspotify C sending zeros at the end of track

Tags: libspotify

I'm using `libspotify SDK`, C library for win32.

I think to have a right setup, every session callback is registered. I don't understand why i can't receive the call for `end_of_track`, while `music_delivery` continues to be called with zero padding `22050` long frames.

I attempt to start playing first loading the track with `sp_session_load`; till it returns `SP_ERROR_IS_LOADING` I post a message on my message queue (synchronization method I've used, `PostMessage` win32 API) in order to reload again with same API `sp_session_load`. As soon as it returns `SP_ERROR_OK` I use the `sp_session_play` and the `music_delivery` starts immediately, with correct frames.

I don't know why at the end of track the `libspotify` runtime then start sending zero padded frames, instead of calling `end_of_track` callback.
In other conditions it works perfectly: I've used the `sp_track` obtained from a album browse, so the track is fully loaded at the moment I load to the current session for playing: with this track, it works fine with `end_of_track` called correctly. In the case with padding error, I search the track using its Spotify URI and got the results; in this case the track metadata are not still ready (at the play attempt) so I used that kind of "polling" on `sp_session_load` with `PostMessage`.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I think the issue was that I was consuming the data too fast without giving other threads time to do any work since I was spending all of my time in the `music_delivery` callback. I found that if I add some throttling and notify the main thread that it can wake up to do some processing, the extra zeros at the end of track is reduced to one delivery of 22,050 frames (or 500ms at 44.1kHz).

Here is an example of what I added to my callback, heavily borrowed from the `jukebox.c` example provided with the SDK:

```c
/* Buffer 1 second of data, then notify the main thread to do some processing */
if (g_throttle > format->sample_rate) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_notify_mutex);
    g_notify_do = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&g_notify_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_notify_mutex);

    // Reset the throttle counter
    g_throttle = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

As I said, there was still 22,050 frames of zeros delivered before the track stopped, but I believe `libspotify` may purposely do this to ensure that the duration calculated by the number of frames received (`song_duration_ms = total_frames_delivered / sample_rate * 1000`) is greater than or equal to the duration reported by `sp_track_duration`. In my case, the track I was trying to stream was `172,000ms` in duration, without the extra padding the duration calculated is `171,796ms`, but with the padding it was `172,296ms`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks anf sorry for late answer, i did the same, a sort of buffering...